# How to axiomatize syntactic identity in the language of propositional logic with identity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have the language of propositional logic with identity as follows:

${\cal L}::=p\,|\,\neg\phi\,|\,\phi\circ\phi$, where $\circ\in\{\land,\lor,\to,\leftrightarrow,=\}$

How can we axiomatize statements containing identity $=$, *in this language*, in a way that captures syntactic identity between statements? To illustrate, I'm interested in the identities and unidentified below to follow from such an axiomatization: $\phi_1\land\psi_1=\phi_2\land\psi_2\,\to\,(\phi_1=\psi_1\land\phi_2=\psi_2)$, $\phi\neq\neg\neg\phi$, $\phi\lor\psi\neq\neg\gamma$, $\phi{\land}\phi\neq \phi$, where all the Greek letters schematically stand for sentences of $\cal L$.

I'm expecting the workings of the notion of syntactic identity to be somewhat clear here: two formulas are syntactically identical if they are, as it were, concatenations of the exact same symbols, in the exact same order. It's as if formulas are just finite sequences or tuples of symbols (from among the set $\{p,q,...,\land,\lor,\to,\leftrightarrow,=\}$), and their identity condition is determined in the expected way, as a componentwise identity between the symbols in use. For instance, consider formulas like $p\land q$ and $p\lor q$ as shorthands for the triples $(p,\land, q)$ and $(p,\lor, q)$, respectively; that results in the unidentity $p\land q\neq p\lor q$, assuming that $\land$ isn't syntactically the same as $\lor$.

I've been struggling to find a neat axiomatization, formulated in $\cal L$, that gets all instances of syntactic identity and unidentity right. Do you think such an axiomatization exists? Do we need richer languages for such axiomatizations?

Comment: What is the meaning of "axiomatize" here?

Comment: What is unsatisfactory about the axiomatization consisting of the schemas (1) $\varphi=\varphi$ when $\varphi$ is a sentence, and (2) $\lnot(\varphi=\psi)$ when $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are distinct sentences? If you can clarify that, the question may become more answerable. Regarding your last question: My opinion is that no, we do not need such an axiomatization. I really don't see what the point would be.

Comment: Sorry, my last question has lost some words for some reason. I meant to ask this: Do we need richer languages for such axiomatizations? E.g., do we need higher-order languages?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think your two suggested schemas should be fine? We can define syntactic identity separately (for formulas-as-sequences-of-symbols) and then add those schemata, where by 'distinct sentences' we mean the not syntactically identical. Is that the suggestion?

Comment: Your title question about syntactic identity should have nothing to do with whatever semantic axiomatization you have in your mind. There's a syntactic theorem for most propositional logic called *unique readability theorem* (you can search online further for ref) to decide syntactic identity of any 2 wffs. As for your semantic motivation for your proprietary axiomatization, it's better to show a concrete model for your concerned motivation which current popular systems lack, thus why we'd better consider your new proposed axiomatic system...

Comment: IMO syntactic identity is at the meta-level... The language has "names": sentential variables, for objects: proposition/truth values. We may have (as usual for languages) different names for the same object, like $p$ and $\lnot \lnot p$. When we formalize the calculus with schematic letters: $\varphi, \psi$ we already know that we can instantiate different occurrences of a schematic letter with the **same** formula (string) and not with two "equivalent" ones.